# Where should I use escape function in the following code?

Tags: php, codeigniter

How should I use the escape function in the following code?

```
public function Add_video()
{
    $Game_type  = $_POST['Game'];
    $Video_type = $_POST['video_type'];
    $Url        = $_POST['url'];
    $Url        = mysql_escape_string($Url); // Video url 

    $Data       = array(
        'Game_type' => $Game_type,
        'Video_type' => $Video_type,
        'Video_url' => $Url
    );

    $this->db->insert('videos', $Data);
}
```

Comment: If you are using Codeigniter your queries will automatically be escaped

Comment: But in my database '<','>' are replaced by &lt and &gt..

Comment: try using urlencode() - will post an example later at home

http://uk3.php.net/urlencode

Comment: thank you for considering me. I've found solution. All have to do is just use htmlspecialchars_decode() function.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for any post or get request please do use Codeigniter's native [functions](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html)

see following code

```
public function Add_video()
{
    $Game_type  = $this->input->post('Game');
    $Video_type = $this->input->post('video_type');
    $Url        = $this->input->post('url');
    //$Url        = mysql_escape_string($Url); // Video url 

    $data       = array(
        'Game_type' => $Game_type,
        'Video_type' => $Video_type,
        'Video_url' => $Url
    );

    $this->db->insert('videos', $data);
}
```

or simply create your array right away:

```
 $data       = array(
            'Game_type' => $this->input->post('Game'),
            'Video_type' => $this->input->post('video_type'),
            'Video_url' => $this->input->post('url'),
        );
```

I recommend you to not use capitalization on first letter eg.: "game" instead of "Game"